# jFrog Artifactory tagging only files inside a folder

Tags: api, unix, artifactory, jfrog-cli

I tried tagging the folder in jFrog which recursively tagged all the files, but would like to exclude the folder from getting tagged.

is there a way to tag just the files inside a folder using the jFrog rest API?

```
curl -s -u username:password -X POST https://server:port/api/storage/pathtoFolder?properties=key=value
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by using JFrog CLI (free tool by JFrog):

https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/CLI/CLI+for+JFrog+Artifactory#CLIforJFrogArtifactory-SettingPropertiesonFiles

What you can do is to use wildcards on the folder level and that will do the trick :)

Comment: Thanks. But I wanted to do it via the rest api

Comment: For doing it via the rest api you will need to have a file list of the folder and then run on each item. Another option is set it on the folder recursively, as you did, and delete the property from the folder itself. I don't really like the second approach as in case you already have a property with that key on the folder it will override it.